# Refreshing a label through jtextfield

Tags: java, jlabel, jtextfield

i am developing a project to a class and i came up with a stand-still.
So, what i want to do is to refresh the label when the user presses enter in the textfield to verify the ID.
**Here is my code to catch when "enter" key is pressed, it's an event of the textfield "txtNbi":**

```
if (evt.getKeyCode() == 10) {
    this.BI = txtNbi.getText();
    String BIs[];
    BIs = DadosAplicacao.getInstance().getBIs();
    for (int i = 0; i < BIs.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("BI: " + this.BI + "\nBIlista: " + BIs[i]);
        if (this.BI.equals(BIs[i])) {
            encontrou.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/pt/estg/dint/imagens/Ok.png")));
            this.repaint();
        } else {
            encontrou.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/pt/estg/dint/imagens/Cross.png")));
            this.repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

**txtNbi** = name of my textfield;
**BIs** = array of strings that get pre-inserted IDs from the 'DadosAplicacao' class;
**encontrou** = name of my label that receives the image as an icon

### So here is my problem:


I have the following data:
- BIs[0] = 12345678
- BIs[1] = 87654321
- BIs[2] = 54321678

When i type in the first 2 the label doesn't change to the "Ok.png" icon, but when i type the last one the label changes his icon to "Ok.png"!

Can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: Don't use a KeyListener, it's likely that the key stroke is being consumed by the field, instead use an ActionListener instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a `break` after you found the typed ID

```
if(this.BI.equals(BIs[i]))
{
    encontrou.setIcon(newjavax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/pt/estg/dint/imagens/Ok.png")));
    this.repaint();
    break;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! it works! but what does the break do there? can u explain me?

Comment: You can use an unlabeled break to terminate a for, while, or do-while loop immediately. In your case you need to find a specific ID and when you find it you have to change the icon and then stop. because if you continue comparing other array elements with the desired ID you will always get 'false' from  <code>this.BI.equals(BIs[i])</code>  and so your code will re-change the icon to Cross.png.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the DocumentListener class:

```
txtNbi.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
     public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent documentEvent) {
     //add the code handling the different conditions here
     }
});
```